# Android get Directory content from web server

Tags: php, android

Actually I'm developing an app for android.

The app should display all images from a specific directory stored in a webspace.

**Example**

**Host**: www.example.org

**Folder**: /images

**Foldercontent**

/images/file.png

/images/file2.png

/images/folder/file3.png

I already found out how to display a single image provided by a URL (used the Picasso library)

```
ImageView appImage = new ImageView(getActivity());

Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("http://www.example.org/images/file.png").into(appImage);
```

Now my question is, how can I display all images located in a directory and all subfolders?

I have implemented a PHP Script on the Server which provides my the name of all files located in the directory as a text form, but how do I get those names in Android?
How can I call the PHP Script and store the output in a String Array for example?

Or is there a better solution for this, without a PHP Script?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The PHP Script should be the best approach.

If it acts as a Rest webservice (it should) you just need to perform a really common task (Calling REST Services)

Here is a really simple implementation using the URL class (Its made from my thoughts so it probably has errors, long time since i used BufferedReader)

```
URL url = new URL("yourURLString");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
String response = "";
String readed = null;
readed = br.read();
while(readed != null)
{
    response += readed;
}
```

After that you should have the response of your script on the response String, then parse it to get the values you need and show it in your app.

Hope this helps.